# * What went wrong: Task 'bootJar' not found in project ':app-cloud-config-server'. * Try: Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle

This is my first question on stack overflow.
So I am trying to run the build my springboot application app-cloud-config-server on my local system.

I ran this cd /app; ./gradlew app-cloud-config-server:build command on the terminal and got the below error:

- What went wrong: Task 'bootJar' not found in project ':app-cloud-config-server'.  * Try: Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

I checked multiple threads for the solution to this error based on which I tried

1. Including this in my build.gradle file to find the missing bootJar task

```
bootJar {
   mainClassName = 'foxtrot.infra.applications.cloudconfig.CloudConfigServerApplication'
   baseName = 'spring-boot-integration-test'
   version = '0.1.0'
}
```

Couldn't resolve

2. Applied the below plugins

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
```

3. Did gradle clean and followed the same steps
   still couldn't resolve the issue.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you should post entire `build.gradle`.

Comment: Shall I attach the whole file?